# Geometry Nodes: How to select a spline based on the position of a point?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I tried many times to use the Curve of Point node, but i'm missing something and I couldn't find examples of how to use it. For my specific question, I try to select the spline with the point situated at (0,0,0), and my intuition tell me to do something like in the screenshot, but it's not working. As we see, the selected curve is not the right one. What could be the solution?
[image]

Comment: Looks ok. Maybe the object is shifted in Z axis? Can you share the screenshot so that z position in spreadsheet is visible?

Comment: Shifted? There really is a point at (0,0,0), this is on the spreadsheet. I will update my screenshot with the values.

Comment: Hm, well... can you share the file then? You can use https://blend-exchange.com/ for sharing *.blend here

Comment: https://blend-exchange.com/b/8elVB3wx/

Comment: I see now, your vertex order has been changed then you convert mesh to curve because you are using extrude. Should be easy to fix

Comment: How should I proceed? I tried to repeat the problem using a simple setup and the problem was the same, so I don't think it's that easy.

Answer (score 2):

So because that problem caused by point order (points in spline should have the right order instead of mesh) the easiest way to fix that is that: Get source for *Sample Nearest* after convertion to curves:

[image]

The only problem is that *Sample Nearest* requires mesh, so it should be converted back

Another solution is to use a Mesh island index that should correspond to curve index after convertion:

[image]

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!